# my python modules (matplotlib, numpy) don't work

Tags: python, module, numpy, matplotlib, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using mac mountain lion(10.8.1) and python(2.7.3). And I want to use python matplotlib, numpy modules for figuring a graph.
But there's not matplotlib, numpy ver for mountain lion.
I've tested with matplotlib(1.1.1), numpy(1.7.0b1). They had been installed.
But it doesn't work like below. I just need a graph. Can mountain lion user draw a graph by python?

```
>>>import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from bumpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): no suitable image found. Did find:
        /Libraray/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Comment: If you are an academic user (e.g. student or researcher), I would highly recommend the [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/edudownload.php)- it lets you install Python with useful packages like numpy, scipy, matplotlib and others built in.

Comment: (1) How were matplotlib and NumPy installed? Did you do it yourself? (2) Is it the native python you're using?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I checked numpy version. There's my fault. When I install numpy 1.6.2 py 2.7 macox 10.6 version, it works! I just tried by macox 10.3 version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific "for Mountain Lion" numpy or matplotlib. The only compatibility consideration would be the python version, which in your case is fine. My guess is that you just need to force it to build in 64bit only:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install numpy
```